# WebService PHP+JSON - Como ler retorno

Tags: php, json

Ola!

Pessoal, gostaria de entender como ler o retorno, com a seguinte estrutura:

```
$ws = array(

   'categoria' => array(
      array(
         'cat1' => array(
            'dado1' => $dado1,
            'dado2'=>$dado2                                                             
         ),
         'subcategoria'=>array(
            'dado3'=>$dado3,
            'dado4'=>$dado4,
         )
      ),
   ),
);

$json = json_encode($ws, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$url = 'https://link.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Accept: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json),
"Content-Type: application/json",
));

$jsonRet = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Com o código acima realizo o envio. Agora como faço para extrair individualmente os dados de retorno?

Ele vem nesse formato:

```
{"data":{"nome1":João,"status":["ativo"]}}
```

Quero poder interpretar somente o status, ou o `nome1`, separadamente com php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$retorno = json_decode($jsonRet);
 $status = $retorno->data->status;`

Comment: Resolvido! Muito obrigado...

Answer (score 1):

tente isso

`$retorno = json_decode($jsonRet);
 $status = $retorno['data']['status'];`

Comment: Testei assim:                                                                                       
 $retorno = json_decode($jsonRet);
 $status = $retorno['data']['status'];                                                                               echo $status;                                                                                                              * Mas não houve visualização, ocorreu erro na sintaxe...

Comment: dê um var_dump($retorno); e poste aqui o q foi exibido

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$retorno' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: parece q a $jsonRet n esta retornando um valor; tente da um var_dump dela pra ver o q aparece

Comment: Eu havia esquecido de colocar o parenteses no var_dump(); Com o $retorno fica tudo em branco, nada aparece na tela. e com o $jsonRet aparece:     string(208) "{"data":{"nome1":João,"status":"[ativo]",

Comment: $retorno = json_decode($jsonRet); transforma o obj json em array... vc pode postar o código q gera o retorno?

Comment: Sim, coloquei nesse formato como você indicou no inicio, json_decode($jsonRet); Mas no var_dump() nada acontece, fica vazio a tela...nada aparece

Comment: kkk espera ai eu q errei aqui o correto seria $status = $retorno->data->status; tente ai ai vc da um echo pra ver se imprime o valor

Comment: Perfeito! =D ...Você pode colocar esse trecho como resposta? Assim marco como resolvido para finalizarmos